# Factorial and Multiplication

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

KISS: Is there anything I could do with

$$ {xN\choose yN}$$

Given any size $N$, I would like to see how many ways there are to choose a fraction $yN$ out of $xN$. In factorials, that is

$$\frac{(xN)!}{(yN)![(x-y)N]!}$$

I have never seen any $(ab)!$ factorial rule, nor is there any to my intuition. Is there?

Comment: Because $a! = \Gamma(a+1)$ there is such a _rule_ if $N$ is positive integer, see e.g.
http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E6, but I doubt if it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to express $(ab)!$ as something else in an exact manner. However for large numbers, [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) of the factorial can be useful, if the sought result is numerical.
The Stirling approximation reads
$$ n!\approx n^n\mathrm e^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}.$$
It is more handable in its logarithmic form
$$\ln n!\approx n\ln n-n+O(\ln n).$$
The last expression is extensively used in statistical physics.